# Add To Cart Doesn't Work

Tags: java, jsp, cart

Hi I am trying to implement Add To Cart Mechanism in my web Application.
So that's why temporary i have created 3 JSP pages that implement such mechanism.  But it is not working properly.

I have also created session uniquely for to identify specific user session but it is not actually implemented in all page.

Following Is My Code :

**test.jsp**

```
<%
    Random rkey = new Random();
    int randomkey = Math.abs(rkey.nextInt());
    String sdata = "keyur"+randomkey;   

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmmss");
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    String sess = "keyur"+randomkey+dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
    session.setAttribute("KEYUR", sess);
%>
<% response.sendRedirect("test1.jsp"); %>
```

**test1.jsp**

```
Hello <%= session.getAttribute("KEYUR")%>

<%
    String a="shirt",b="jeans";
    int a1 = 10,b1=20;
    Double a2=100.00,b2=200.00;
%>
<br><br>
A : <a href="test2.jsp?item=<%=a%>&qty=<%=a1%>&price=<%=a2%>" id="a1" name="a1">Add To Cart</a><br><br>
A1 : <a href="test2.jsp?item=<%=b%>&qty=<%=b1%>&price=<%=b2%>" id="a2" name="a2">Add To Cart</a>
```

**test2.jsp**

```
Hello <%= session.getAttribute("KEYUR")%><br><br><br><br>

Your Cart :
<%
    List<String> pname = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<Integer> pqty = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Double> ppr = new ArrayList<Double>();
%>
<%
    pname.add(request.getParameter("item"));
    pqty.add(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("qty")));    
    ppr.add(Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("price")));
    Double total=0.00;
%>
<br><br>
<%
    for(int i = 0;i < pname.size();i++)
    {
        String name = pname.get(i);
        Integer qty1 = pqty.get(i);
        Double pr1 = ppr.get(i);        
        %>
            Name : <%= name %><br>
            Qty : <%= qty1 %><br>
            Price : <%= pr1 %><br><br>
            Total : <%= total += qty1*pr1 %> 
        <%      
    }
%>
```

Right now i have taken static data, if it will work then I'll try it with dynamic data.
Anyone tell me why only one item display in cart.
Suppose user click on Add To Cart then it redirect to test2.jsp and again back to test1.jsp then click on second add to cart then cart should be appended not overwrite.
But currently it is overwriting.

Any Suggestion Please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**test2.jsp**

```
List<String> pname = new ArrayList<String>(); //size is 0
```

...

```
pname.add(request.getParameter("item")); //size is 1
```

That's why you get just one item.

By the way, make your self a favour, don't use JSP scriptlets; use JSTL or write your own tags (look for Java Custom tags)

Comment: But suppose I want to add multiple item then what I ll have to do ?

Comment: Keep on adding to pname. Anyway, this is the wrong approach.First of all you should have a class to describe your cart object which wraps item, unit price and quantity , call it CartItem. Then you should use an List<CartItem> and save in the Session. Finally, you should get your List<CartItem> from the session and loop across your list. Good luck

Comment: I have tried to add more item in pname but it stores only one item and display it. I know this one is wrong approach, I know that I have to create separate class for cart to store items. I am just asking that is it possible in this way ?

Comment: Store information: You have to store your objects (CartItem, Strings, it is up to you!) to a List and then put the List in the Session. Read information: get the List from the session then loop the list and display your objects. Does it make sense?

Comment: I am getting it somewhat. If you have some small example or any link then please sir share it with me. I need to resolve it as soon as possible. I don't understand that how to store and read list from session...

Comment: Say that you need just a String (let's leave CartItem out for the moment) to describe what you want to buy. In the first jsp you will have something like List<String> cartItems = new List<String>(); then String item1 = "eggs"; String item2 = "cheese"; String item3 = "pepper"; Then you do something like cartItems.add(item1); cartItems.add(item2); cartItems.add(item3); Then session.put("yourkey",cartItems); Now you have a object in the session with 3 items. Haven't you? In the second jsp, List<String> cartItems = (List<String>)session.get("yourkey"); now you can loop cartItems and see your items

Comment: if this works, then use ItemCart instead of strings. Good luck

Comment: Yes I have got it completely. Let me try this one. This is so good and simple. Thank You for the help.

Answer (score 1):

This procudure looking very Bad codding for store a cart items...
But still you can store as many you want in List
In your page when every time a Test2.jsp called the new keywprd initilize a new cart lists..
thats why previous value get losts....
instead of this code

```
<%
List<String> pname = new ArrayList<String>()
List<Integer> pqty = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Double> ppr = new ArrayList<Double>();
%>
```

use deceleration block for decleration

```
<%!
List<String> pname = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Integer> pqty = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Double> ppr = new ArrayList<Double>();
%>
```

after that you can store as many you want ....But there will be possible some duplicate values...to remove duplicate you can use Set at the place of List

I think you have got your query's answer.....

Answer (score 0):

The reason why only one item is displayed is because you are inserting only one item in Lists pname, pqty, ppr.

Use a for loop in-order to insert. So that it contains multiple orders or items..

Hope it will help.

Comment: did you get noticed from page Test1.jsp only one item add to cart request comming so what for will not work in this sictuation..